# Primefaces datatable scroll

Tags: primefaces, primefaces-datatable

I have a primefaces datatable and I want to scroll it
I disable scrollable=true and add css for scroll table
but something get wrong :
the header of datatable doesn't fix and scroll with body

I add this css only :
.ui-datatable-tablewrapper{
overflow: auto
height:500px;
}

thanks if anyone can help me in this case

Comment: Have a look at https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/scroll.xhtml

Comment: thank's for your response.But I tried it before , by Scrollable=true all the alignment of header and column mismatch.  this issue didnt help me.

Comment: It is working in the showcase and for me it is also working.